# Get Latest Vesion Can't Find References

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, reference

I accidentally deleted my solution folder.  No problem because I've got everything under source control.  I did "Get Latest Version" because I'm the only developer and I check in very regularly.  I now have 40 Warnings and 17 Errors which, from what I can tell, all relate to references.

This has happened several times before, but the errors were mostly about OAuth.  Now there are a lot of different references listed.

In the past, I have just created a new project and copy and pasted my code in.  This is very wrong, I know, but I have searched the internet and SO to no avail.

Does this happen to other people? and why? and how did you fix it?  I have yet to discern a specific action of mine causing this.  It appears random, but I know it's probably me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using TFS, try Get Specifc Version. And select Overwrite writable files.

TFS thinks it knows which files are on your system (it's wrong) and won't give you a new copy unless you force it to.

<humor>
Q: How do you fix it?
A: Use a real source control system rather than TFS. (CVS, Subversion, Mercurial, git, etc...)
</humor>

Comment: Haha. Novice here; it was the first/easiest thing once I realized I needed source control.  I tried your suggestion, but got the same errors.  I'm gonna post a screenshot of some of them.

Comment: I can't post a screenshot because I don't have enough rep. They are mainly "The referenced component ... could not be found." and "Type ... is not defined."

Comment: Are the objects that cannot be referenced things that you have defined or are they in other libraries (assemblies)?   If they are in other assemblies check your project properties to be sure the necessary references are defined.  -- and make sure your project files are checked into the repository, too.

Comment: They are in other libraries and some are pretty standard libraries.  I tried checking my project properties, but they looked fine(?).  I copy and pasted my code into a new project again and it works again.  Going forward: To prevent this I should put my project files under source control? The only files I can tell that are not in tfs are the _packages_ and _My Project_ folder.

Comment: Nvm. I just found those two folders in TFS also.  I'm learning a lot.  Got any other suggestions for what could have caused it to break? Thanks for your help.